# Transfer Authentication from Webbrowser to Indy CookieManager

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

How do you put the cookie from the Webbrowser to an Indy CookieManager for Http Request.

I get the cookies after i login in to a website like this..

Test Project = http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/373536/Cookie-Tester-rar.html

```
procedure TForm1.WebBrowser1DownloadComplete(Sender: TObject);
var
document: IHTMLDocument2;
cookies:tstringlist;
begin
cookies:=tstringlist.Create;
document := WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
cookies.Add(document.cookie);
cookies.savetofile('test.txt');
end;
```

**HttpOnly Cookie Method.**

```
function GetCookie(host: PAnsiChar): PAnsiChar;
const
  INTERNET_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = 8192;
var
  hModule: THandle;
  lp: Pointer;
  InternetGetCookieEx: function(lpszUrl, lpszCookieName, lpszCookieData
    : PAnsiChar; var lpdwSize: DWORD; dwFlags: DWORD; lpReserved: pointer)
    : BOOL; stdCall;
  CookieSize: DWORD;
  CookieData: PAnsiChar;
begin
  LoadLibrary('wininet.dll');
  hModule := GetModuleHandle('wininet.dll');
  if hModule <> 0 then
  begin
    @InternetGetCookieEx := GetProcAddress(hModule, 'InternetGetCookieExA');
    if @InternetGetCookieEx <> nil then
    begin
      CookieSize := 1024;
      Cookiedata := AllocMem(CookieSize);
      if InternetGetCookieEx(host, nil, Cookiedata, CookieSize, INTERNET_COOKIE_HTTPONLY, nil) then
      result:=cookiedata;
      FreeMem(Cookiedata);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You are not showing how you are actually extracting the cookies from the browser and storing them in the `TStringList`.

Comment: Oh no, you're leaking `cookies` man!

Comment: @WoutervanNifterick What is that supposed to mean?!

Comment: You're creating `cookies` without eating them in the end. Imagine what would happen if you keep doing that. :) What I meant is that you need to free the tstringlist that you're creating. It's unrelated to your question, but it's sloppy coding.

Comment: Ah i didn't understand you :)

Comment: In XE2, you should be using `InternetGetCookieExW()` instead. You also be asking `InternetGetCookieEx()` for the actual cookie length instead of just blindly assuming 1024 characters.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Can you post an answer that works with Hotmail? Thanks.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Here is the project. http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/373536/Cookie-Tester-rar.html

Comment: I don't have a Hotmail account to test with.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Maybe with HTTPServerProxy this would work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you tagged your question with multiple Delphi version tags, I assume you are using different releases of Indy with each Delphi version, is that right?  Indy's cookie handling logic has changed a bit over the years, and underwent a major re-wrote in early 2011 to account for [RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265) (which obsoleted all previous cookie RFCs).

Under the current Indy 10 release, adding cookies manually is done using the `TIdCookieManager.AddServerCookie()` or `TIdCookieManager.AddServerCookies()` method:

```
procedure AddServerCookie(const ACookie: String; AURL: TIdURI);
procedure AddServerCookies(const ACookies: TStrings; AURL: TIdURI);
```

Both parameters are required, where `ACookie` is a `name=value; parameters` string for a single cookie, and `AURL` is the URL where the cookie came from (used for validating the cookie data and initializing any default values where needed), for example:

```
procedure TForm1.WebBrowser1DownloadComplete(Sender: TObject);
var
  document: IHTMLDocument2;
  cookies: TStringList;
  uri: TIdURI;
begin
  document := WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
  cookies := TStringList.Create;
  try
    // fill cookies as needed, one cookie per line
    uri := TIdURI.Create(document.URL);
    try
      IdCookieManager1.AddServerCookies(cookies, uri);
    finally
      uri.Free;
    end;
  finally
    cookies.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Keep in mind that the `document.cookie` property can contain multiple cookies in it, so you will have to split the cookies up manually before you can then pass them to `TIdCookieManager`.  Also, the `document.cookie` property uses the `;` character to separate cookies, but it also uses ';' for separating the `name=value` and `parameters` values for a single cookie, so you are going to have to do a little bit of parsing when splitting up the `document.cookie` data.

Comment: @RemyLebau I updated the question maybe with this function it will be better

Comment: also this will get executed three times and will not work if you try to login in to Hotmail Live. 
"Cookies must be allowed Your browser is currently set to block cookies."