# TidCookieManager & Redirects

Tags: delphi, authentication, delphi-xe2, indy, indy10

I get cookie from InternetGetCookieEx on DownloadComplete WebBrwoser. When trying to login to hotmail it get's through but then get's redirected. Even though Gmail works.
I am trying to figure out a universal solution to transfer Authenication from WebBrowser to IdCookieManager for Web Parsing.

Test Project = http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/373536/Cookie-Tester-rar.html

**Cookies aswell as redirects are enabled on IdHTPP.**

> Cookies must be allowed Your browser is currently set to block
>   cookies. Your browser must allow cookies before you can use Windows
>   Live ID.

```
    function GetCookie(host: string): string;
    const
      INTERNET_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = 8192;
    var
      hModule: THandle;
      lp: Pointer;
      InternetGetCookieEx: function(lpszUrl, lpszCookieName, lpszCookieData
        : PAnsiChar; var lpdwSize: DWORD; dwFlags: DWORD; lpReserved: pointer)
        : BOOL; stdCall;
      CookieSize: DWORD;
      CookieData: PAnsiChar;
    begin
      LoadLibrary('wininet.dll');
      hModule := GetModuleHandle('wininet.dll');
      if hModule <> 0 then
      begin
        @InternetGetCookieEx := GetProcAddress(hModule, 'InternetGetCookieExA');
        if @InternetGetCookieEx <> nil then
        begin
          CookieSize := 1024;
          Cookiedata := AllocMem(CookieSize);
          if InternetGetCookieEx(PAnsiChar(AnsiString(host)), nil, Cookiedata, CookieSize, INTERNET_COOKIE_HTTPONLY, nil) then
          result:=cookiedata;
          FreeMem(Cookiedata);
        end;
      end;
    end;

procedure EmbeddedWB1DocumentComplete(ASender: TObject; const pDisp: IDispatch;
  var URL: OleVariant);
var
  document: IHTMLDocument2;
  cookies: TStringList;
  uri: TIdURI;
begin
  document := EmbeddedWB1.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
  cookies := TStringList.Create;
  try 
    cookies.Delimiter:=';';
    //cookies.DelimitedText:=GetCookie(document.url);
    cookies.DelimitedText:=document.cookie;
    uri := TIdURI.Create(document.url);
    try
      IdCookieManager1.AddServerCookies(cookies,uri);
      EmbeddedWB1.LoadFromString(http.Get(document.url));
    finally
      uri.Free;
    end;
  finally
    cookies.Free;
  end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13235897), you need to pre-parse the cookies you are extracting from the web browser.  It is not enough to simply split the cookie string as-is on `;` characters, since that delimiter is used to both delimit individual cookies from each other as well as delimit `name=value` data from `parameter` data within a single cookie.  If you just split the entire string without taking that into account, your `TStringList` is not going to end up with correct cookie data, so you end up passing bad data to `TIdCookieManager`.

You might also consider using the `NavigateComplete/2` events, as the `DocumentComplete` event might be too late when redirects are involved.

Comment: i used cookies that were intercepted from HTTP Analyzer it still shows the "Cookies must be allowed Your browser".
It works with Gmail,FB,Twitter,Yahoo...

Comment: Without seeing the actual HTTP traffic, the actual cookies that the web browser is providing, and the actual cookies that `TIdCookieManager` is storing, it is really hard to diagnose your problem. There are too many factors that can go wrong with the code you have shown so far. You might not be getting all of the cookies at the right times. You might not be parsing and passing them to `TIdCookieManager` correctly. It might be rejecting cookies as invalid.  It might not be sending cookies back to the server on subsequent requests. There is just too much missing information to troubleshoot with.

Comment: I think Hotmail uses some AUTH WRAP there for this won't work i think.

Comment: Here is the project. http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/373536/Cookie-Tester-rar.html