# Add Cookie field to header of post request

Tags: http, delphi, indy, httpcookie

I would like to send post request like following by program is written in delphi.
[image: Reuquest of web browser]
There is a cookie field in request header (in red rectangle).
I wrote following source code.

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    uri : TIdURI;
    cookie : TIdCookieManager;
    HTTP : TIdHTTP;
    vals: TStringList;
    url : String;
    response : TStringStream;
begin
    HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create();
    HTTP.AllowCookies := True;
    HTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
    HTTP.HandleRedirects := True;
    cookie := TIdCookieManager.Create();
    uri := TIdURI.Create('www.hoge.com');
    cookie.AddServerCookie('ASP.NET_SessionId=test', uri);
    HTTP.CookieManager := cookie;
    vals := TStringList.Create;
    response :=  TStringStream.Create('');
    vals.Add('__EVENTTARGET=');
    vals.Add('__EVENTARGUMENT=');
    vals.Add('__VIEWSTATE=/wEPDwUINzcxNjQyMjkPFgIeE1ZhbGlkYXRlUmVxdWVzdE1vZGUCAWRkEHyFbwQQE8tM5FKRr3UELd00osRNQBzu31XZl1yd86A=');
    vals.Add('__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=A7C0DD1C');
    vals.Add('__EVENTVALIDATION=/wEdAAZkcRcs1jgA2rEUAtpu7qzIhFuNiVVNuLciluwM7Vty0gJCK50467l5FRCktGxHOlNKe/Y7d9SBufbGEp2w5OLHqFe59uEio+bAp/33YZOR3aKeKEbp39eHc9mbdvkCgxAPflO5NLAHc5uwdZn6JOnwKMi9h+dluqFLpmg3gO25cg==');
    vals.Add('ddlLanguage=ja-JP');
    vals.Add('tbUserId=myid');
    vals.Add('tbPassword=hoge');
    vals.Add('btnLogin=login');

    url :=  TIdURI.ParamsEncode('ReturnUrl=/GssNet/main/default.aspx');
    url := TIdURI.URLEncode('www.hoge.com/GssNet/login,aspx?ReturnUrl=/GssNet/main/default.aspx');
    try
        HTTP.Post('http://www.hoge.com/GssNet/login,aspx', vals, response);
    Except
        on EIdHTTPProtocolException do
        begin
          ShowMessage(Memo1.TextHint);
        end;
    end;
end;
```

But cookie field is not included in request header. Following is result of packet capture. when I execute my program. Please teach me the way to add cookie field to request header.

[image: Rquest of my program]

Comment: Maybe helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13235897/transfer-authentication-from-webbrowser-to-indy-cookiemanager/13239097#13239097

Comment: Have you tried to create the URI with http? `TIdURI.Create('http://www.hoge.com/');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @smooty86 said in comments, you need to include the `http://` portion of the URL when adding a cookie manually. You also need to include the full path to the resource that is being requested, otherwise the cookie will only be valid for requests to the root `/` path.

Also, your calls to `TIdURI.ParamsEncode()` and `TIdURI.URLEncode()` are useless since you are not using the encoded `url` variable.  If you are going to take the time to encode a URL than make sure to actually use it.

You are also leaking all of your objects.

Try this instead:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  uri : TIdURI;
  HTTP : TIdHTTP;
  vals : TStringList;
  url : String;
  response : TStringStream;
begin
  try
    response := TStringStream.Create('');
    try
      vals := TStringList.Create;
      try
        vals.Add('__EVENTTARGET=');
        vals.Add('__EVENTARGUMENT=');
        vals.Add('__VIEWSTATE=/wEPDwUINzcxNjQyMjkPFgIeE1ZhbGlkYXRlUmVxdWVzdE1vZGUCAWRkEHyFbwQQE8tM5FKRr3UELd00osRNQBzu31XZl1yd86A=');
        vals.Add('__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=A7C0DD1C');
        vals.Add('__EVENTVALIDATION=/wEdAAZkcRcs1jgA2rEUAtpu7qzIhFuNiVVNuLciluwM7Vty0gJCK50467l5FRCktGxHOlNKe/Y7d9SBufbGEp2w5OLHqFe59uEio+bAp/33YZOR3aKeKEbp39eHc9mbdvkCgxAPflO5NLAHc5uwdZn6JOnwKMi9h+dluqFLpmg3gO25cg==');
        vals.Add('ddlLanguage=ja-JP');
        vals.Add('tbUserId=myid');
        vals.Add('tbPassword=hoge');
        vals.Add('btnLogin=login');

        HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
        try
          HTTP.HandleRedirects := True;
          HTTP.AllowCookies := True;
          HTTP.CookieManager := TIdCookieManager.Create(HTTP);

          uri := TIdURI.Create('http://www.hoge.com/GssNet/login,aspx');
          try
            HTTP.CookieManager.AddServerCookie('ASP.NET_SessionId=test', uri);
          finally
            uri.Free;
          end;

          url := TIdURI.URLEncode('http://www.hoge.com/GssNet/login,aspx?ReturnUrl=/GssNet/main/default.aspx');

          HTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
          HTTP.Post(url, vals, response);
        finally
          HTTP.Free;
        end;
      finally
        vals.Free;
      end;

      // use response as needed...
    finally
      response.Free;
    end;
  except
    on EIdHTTPProtocolException do
    begin
      ShowMessage(Memo1.TextHint);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Lastly, why are you sending a request to `login,aspx`?  The correct name is `login.aspx` instead. `login,aspx` does not exist on the server.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I got post request with cookie by adding protocol to urI and fix miss spelling "login,aspx". : )